# Is there a place to catch all signalr errors ?

Tags: c#, signalr

I'm using SignalR with mvc4 c# web application. I created class ChatHub: Hub.
is there an event I can register  in server side to catch all errors thrown from signalr ?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation? [SignalR event Action<Exception> Error](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-Client#event-actionexception-error). This is for the client.

Answer (score 2):

All internal SignalR errors are logged seperately from user defined hub method errors.

To log internal SignalR errors see the SignalR samples web.config diagnostic section: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/samples/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hosting.AspNet.Samples/Web.config

To log hub method invocation errors create a hub pipeline module: [SignalR exception logging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608874/signalr-exception-logging/12613311)

Comment: Sadly, the github link is broken and I was unable to find the replacement.