# Owin handler exceptions from ApiController

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin

I do not understand something related to Owin middleware and how ht exceptions are propagated:

In the startup class I have this code:

```
public static void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.Use<DebugMiddleware>();

    app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Incoming request 1: " + ctx.Request.Path);
        await next();
        Debug.WriteLine("Outgoing request 1: " + ctx.Request.Path);
    });


    app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Incoming request 2: " + ctx.Request.Path);
        await next();
        Debug.WriteLine("Outgoing request 2: " + ctx.Request.Path);
    });

    app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Incoming request 3: " + ctx.Request.Path);

        await ctx.Response.WriteAsync("<html><head></head><body>Hello World</body></html>");
        await next();

        Debug.WriteLine("Outgoing request 3: " + ctx.Request.Path);
    });

    app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Incoming request 4: " + ctx.Request.Path);

       //throw new Exception("New Exception thrown");

        Debug.WriteLine("Outgoing request 4: " + ctx.Request.Path);
    });
}
```

With the DebugMiddleware class looking like this:

```
public class DebugMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{
    public DebugMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next) : base(next) { }

    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Incoming request DebugMiddleware: " + context.Request.Path);

            await Next.Invoke(context);

            Debug.WriteLine("Outgoing request DebugMiddleware: " + context.Request.Path);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Catch exception in DebugMiddleware: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

When I call it I receive something like this, that is ok:

```
Incoming request DebugMiddleware: /
Incoming request 1: /
Incoming request 2: /
Incoming request 3: /
Outgoing request 3: /
Outgoing request 2: /
Outgoing request 1: /
Outgoing request DebugMiddleware: /
```

If I throw an exception in the last middleware, it gets caught and handled in the DebugMiddleware:

```
Incoming request DebugMiddleware: /
Incoming request 1: /
Incoming request 2: /
Incoming request 3: /
Catch exception in DebugMiddleware: New Exception thrown
```

If I add an ApiController and throw an exception, this is not caught anymore in the DebugMiddleware:

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class TestApiController : ApiController
{
    [Route("test")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Test()
    {
        throw new Exception("Exc - Test");
    }
}
```

This is what I see:

```
Incoming request DebugMiddleware: /api/test
Incoming request 1: /api/test
Incoming request 2: /api/test
Incoming request 3: /api/test
Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in Owin.Demo.dll
An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in Owin.Demo.dll but was not handled in user code
Exc - Test
Outgoing request 3: /api/test
Outgoing request 2: /api/test
Outgoing request 1: /api/test
Outgoing request DebugMiddleware: /api/test
```

Is there a way to catch all handled exceptions from the controller in an exception middleware?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api#configure-web-api-for-self-host), you have to register the WebApi handler as middleware as well. Ensure that is being done after your `DebugMiddleware`.

Comment: Yes, I have this added:
            var config = new HttpConfiguration();           
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            app.UseWebApi(config);

Comment: In WebApi, exceptions are handled by default to return HTTP response with code 500. Your DebugMiddleware catch unhandled exceptions. You could have a look to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30918649/unhandled-exception-global-handler-for-owin-katana#answer-50127273)