# How to handle SignalR server exception at client?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, signalr

The error handler is added like this at client:

```
$.connection.hub.url = "/signalr";
$.connection.hub.logging = true;
$.connection.hub.error(function(error) {
    console.log('SignalrAdapter: ' + error);
});

$.connection.hub.start().done(function() { me.onStartDone(); });
// ...
```

At server it is:

```
hubConfiguration.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
```

Accordingly to [the docs](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#handleerrors) this should be enough.

At my exception throwing it just displays a log text for it and does not invoke the handler:

```
[18:18:19 GMT+0000()] SignalR: ... [[[my error description here]]] ...
```

At my cshtml page:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/vendor/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

However if I attach an error handler to the method itself it is got called:

```
$.connection.operatorHub.server.myMethodName(someParam).fail(function(error) {
    console.log("Error handler called: " + error);
});
```

How to handle a general error?

UPDATE.
The answer is below. Also see these:

- http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#handleErrors
- [SignalR, Owin and exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21796087/signalr-owin-and-exception-handling)

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: You can try to disable logging `$.connection.hub.logging = true;`

Comment: @QuentinRoger Nope, it does not help.

Comment: Strangely enough the general error handler got called if I stop on the error handler for the method and evaluate what's got captured in the stack.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I tested on a little chat project [(downloaded here)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SignalR-Getting-Started-b9d18aa9) it seems this method handle only connection errors.

```
$.connection.hub.error(function(error) {
    console.log('SignalrAdapter: ' + error);
});
```

I was able to handle all exceptions with the `HubPipelineModule` class.

1) I created a `SOHubPipelineModule`

```
public class SOHubPipelineModule : HubPipelineModule
{
    protected override void OnIncomingError(ExceptionContext exceptionContext,
                                            IHubIncomingInvokerContext invokerContext)
    {
        dynamic caller = invokerContext.Hub.Clients.Caller;
        caller.ExceptionHandler(exceptionContext.Error.Message);
    }
}
```

2) I Added the module to `GlobalHost.HubPipeline`

```
  // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here
  GlobalHost.HubPipeline.AddModule(new SOHubPipelineModule());
  var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration { EnableDetailedErrors = true };
  app.MapSignalR(hubConfiguration);
```

3) My `ChatHub` class :

```
 public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public void Send(string name, string message)
        {
            throw new Exception("exception for Artyom");
            Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
        }

    }
```

4) In the js I use this code to get my exception message :

```
$.connection.chatHub.client.exceptionHandler = function (error) {
      console.log('SignalrAdapter: ' + error);
      alert('SignalrAdapter: ' + error);
};
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting way. Didn't know about `HubPipelineModule.OnIncomingError`. Tried the little chat project. It works there. But that didn't work at my project. Researching this.  In my project I have signalr groups, autofac, owin and other. And at client... That seems complicated.

Comment: And that seems like some hack. Why not get the error at the first place and not to make this second call to clients?

Comment: I know it's ugly but I think its the only way to handle all  exceptions for a hub :(

Comment: I think this solution is for ASP.NET SignalR and not ASP.NET Core SingnalR because HubPipelineModule is in namespace Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs; Any solution for ASP.NET Core SignalR?

Comment: This is no longer an option in new SignalR versions for .NET Core.

Answer (score 9):

I've used the error handling on the client like this:

It's for SignalR version 2

More detail: [SignalR documentation - How to handle errors in the Hub class](https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#handleErrors)

Hub - AppHub.cs:

```
public class AppHub : Hub
    {
        public void Send(string message)
        {
            throw new HubException("Unauthorized", new { status = "401" });
        }
    }
```

Client-side:

```
$(function () {

            var appHub = $.connection.appHub;

            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {

                appHub.server.send("test message")
                    .fail(function (e) {

                        if (e.source === 'HubException') {
                            console.error("Error message: ", e.message);
                            console.error("Error status: ", e.data.status);
                        }

                    });
            });

        });
```

Comment: Worth to note this was added with SignalR 2

Comment: this works YAY ! should be the answer to retrieve exception on the client-side.