# Call method on hub from HubPipelineModule OnIncomingError event

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I need to implement custom error logging on signalR hubs. This can be done by creating ErrorModule which will inherit from HubPipelineModule and it will be registered on Startup like this

```
   GlobalHost.HubPipeline.AddModule(new ErrorModule());
```

This is my hub

```
 public class FooHub : Hub
{
    public void MethodWithException()
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }

    public void FooMethod()
    {

    }
}
```

And this is my module

```
public class ErrorModule : HubPipelineModule
{
    protected override void OnIncomingError(ExceptionContext exceptionContext, IHubIncomingInvokerContext invokerContext)
    {
        //call foo method on foo hub 

        //log error
    }
}
```

Lets say MethodWithException() is called. It is possible to call FooMethod() on hub which invoked event OnIncomingError ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With something like this :

```
protected override void OnIncomingError(ExceptionContext exceptionContext,
                                                IHubIncomingInvokerContext invokerContext)
        {
            dynamic caller = invokerContext.Hub.Clients.Caller;
            caller.ExceptionHandler(exceptionContext.Error.Message);

            //log something here
            Debug.WriteLine(exceptionContext.Error.Message);
        }
```

**EDIT**

To call a particular method of the hub you can do :

```
protected override void OnIncomingError(ExceptionContext exceptionContext,
                                                IHubIncomingInvokerContext invokerContext)
        {
            var hub = (invokerContext.Hub as HubType); //
            hub.MyMethod("myparam","mysecondparam");

            //log something here
            Debug.WriteLine(exceptionContext.Error.Message);
        }
```

You can find the full code here : [How to handle SignalR server exception at client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36135484/how-to-handle-signalr-server-exception-at-client/36152103#36152103)

Comment: sorry, but i want to call method defined on hub that raised exception

Comment: If you want to get your hub instance you can cast the corresponding hub, I ll update my answer.