# Handle SignalR constructor exceptions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, signalr

Is there anyway to handle exceptions which are thrown in `Hub constructor methods`? 
Currently there is only `HubPipelineModule` which can handles only calling methods related exceptions but **not** constructor exception.

Assume in Hub constructor I get the "Database connection error". Now I want to show the end user a proper message.

I checked the following links but they are not helpful in this case :

- [SignalR exception logging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608874/signalr-exception-logging)
- [SignalR, Owin and exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21796087/signalr-owin-and-exception-handling)

Comment: Sounds like your using your hub in a wrong way if you are doing database calls from its constructor. The hub you have no logic besides handling calls from the client.

Comment: No, I just do some preparation. This preparation is not related to user calls.

Comment: I think the HUB should only be a thin bridge between the clien calls and your backend. Plus its recontructed for each request so you cant keep any data there anyway.

Comment: I know this. I only check some little codes there. Now the main problem is catching and handling exception in a right way at hub construction

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet for handling exceptions thrown from a Hub constructor is probably by providing your own [IHubActivator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.hubs.ihubactivator(v=vs.118).aspx).

[Here is an example of how you can replace SignalR's IHubActivator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555791/using-simpleinjector-with-signalr/15775013#15775013). In that example the purpose for replacing `IHubActivator` was to use Simple Injector to activate hubs, but the same principle applies if you just want to handle/log any exceptions thrown during Hub construction.